# sed extra characters at end of l command

Tags: sed, freebsd

I am trying replace value in a config file with sed in cshell.

However it gives me the error:

```
sed: 1: "/usr/local/etc/raddb/mo ...": extra characters at the end of l command
```

I am trying the following command:

```
sed -i "s/private_key_password = .*/private_key_password = test/" /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available/eap
```

I have looked at examples of sed to do this but they all look similar with what I am doing, what is going wrong here?

Comment: Which OS and sed version do you use?

Comment: FreeBSD, sed version I don't know how to get.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FreeBSD sed requires an argument after `-i` to rename the original file to. For example `sed -i .orig 's/../../' file` will rename he original file to `file.orig`, and save the modified file to `file`.

This is different from GNU `sed`, which doesn't require an argument for the `-i` flag. See [`sed(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for the full documentation. This is one of those useful extensions to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) which is unfortunately implemented inconsistently.

Right now, the `"s/private_key_password = .*/private_key_password = test/"` parts gets interpreted as an argument to `-i`, and `/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available/eap` gets interpreted as the command. Hence the error.

So you want to use:

```
sed -i .orig "s/private_key_password = .*/private_key_password = test/" /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available/eap
```

You can then check if the changes are okay with `diff` and remove `/usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available/eap.orig` if they are.

Comment: Passing an empty string to the `-i` flag will edit in-place i.e. `-i ''`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934903/6548780