# Merge certain fields from one set of YAML files to another

Tags: bash, macos, yaml

I have a set of config files in YAML in one folder and an almost identical set of files in another folder. I'm trying to migrate a site and I need to copy the "uuid" field from the source files into the dest ones. The "uuid" is different for each file. I couldn't find a script to do this, so have attempted with this:

```
SRC=$ROOT/in
DEST=$ROOT/out

cd $SRC
for f in *
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # Find the original UUID
  repl = "$(cat $f |grep uuid)"
  echo "Found UUID: $repl"
  # Replace line into same file
  sed -i "s/^uuid:.*$/$repl/" $DEST/$f
done
```

The $repl variable is never populated, although I know 95% of files have that line and running `cat FILENAME |grep uuid` matches.

Is there a better way to do this? And/or what am I doing wrong?

Update: Thanks @sjsam I have updated. However, output still looks like:

```
Processing views.view.who_s_online.yml file...
./merge-uuids.sh: line 11: repl: command not found
Found UUID: 
sed: 1: "/Users/nic/git/cn-d8/co ...": extra characters at the end of n command
```

Update 2: @Anthon In my case the `uuid: ...` line is always the first line (and it's always a first order key), but not all files actually have this line. In any case shouldn't the sed regex match the `uuid:` prefix wherever it is in the file?

Update 3: Thanks @Anton, After fixing the spaces around `repl` I am actually reading the values, but `sed` still unhappy. Output now:

```
Processing views.view.who_s_online.yml file...
Found UUID: uuid: 07cc0b9d-feda-42cf-9584-cc3f640cbb41
sed: 1: "/Users/nic/git/cn-d8/co ...": extra characters at the end of n command
```

Do a need flag for regex line matching or something?

Update 4: Looks like I'm hitting some FreeBSD/OSX problem (see [sed extra characters at end of l command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620009)). I've tried changing the sed line to:

```
  sed -i .orig "s!^uuid:.*$!${repl}!;" "${DEST}/${f}"
```

and now the errors are like:

```
Processing blah.yml file...
Found UUID: uuid: 5940516b-c188-4d78-8e85-cff8f746ba67
sed: 1: "s!^uuid:.*uuid: 5940516 ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

Update 5: I changed the line to `echo "Found UUID: '${repl}'"` and output is like `Found UUID: 'uuid: eff29d5a-a9fe-4430-a7e9-2a6ecb944ce0'` - i.e. characters are just colon, alphanumeric and spaces.

Comment: Use double quotes  `sed -i "s/^uuid:.*$/$repl/" "$DEST/$f"`. Within single quotes shell variables are not expanded.

Comment: Also `cd $SRC` can be problematic if `$SRC` contains spaces Do `cd "$SRC"`. Worth trying [\[ shellcheck \]](http://shellcheck.net).

Comment: There is no guarantee in YAML that the value for the `uuid` key is on the same line. You should use a real parser (e.g. in Python, Perl, or Ruby)

Comment: You should at least remove the spaces around `=` in `repl = $(...)`

Comment: See my edit, the should solve `sed is unhappy`.

Comment: `sed` is unhappy coz you have `/` in filenames which gets mixed with `s` commands `/`. You're free to use any delimiter.

Comment: I'm now trying `sed -i "s#^uuid:.*$#${repl}#" "$DEST/$f"` but getting the same `extra characters at the end of n command` error

Comment: @NicCottrell : Could you echo the output of `${repl}`?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues with this one:

```
cd "$SRC" # double quote to prevent word splitting
.
.
repl="$(grep '^uuid' "$f")" # no spaces around =, avoid useless use of cat
.
.
sed -i "s#^uuid:.*$#${repl}#" "${DEST}/${f}" 
#Double quote and use `${}` to easily detect errors
#Use a character other than '/' as the substitution delim, I used '#'
```

Comment: It seems that the `$` after `.*` caused the final problem. By changing to `
  sed -i .orig "s!^uuid:.*!${repl}!;" "${DEST}/${f}"` everything worked. Maybe that `$` needed escaping?