# sed -i on FreeBSD

Tags: sed, freebsd

I have got strings stored in two variables (line is current line and new is the replacement). My code looks like this :

```
sed -i "s@line@new@" output_file
```

However, this solution does not work on FreeBSD.

Is there any way to modify this code just a bit so it would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Use:

```
sed -i '' "s@line@new@" output_file
```

On BSD systems (and macOS too), the `sed` command's `-i` option requires a suffix, which may be attached to the `-i` or a separate argument.  However, when the suffix is empty, it must be a separate argument.  This is different from GNU `sed`, where the `-i` option takes an optional suffix, but if specified, it must be attached to the `-i` option.  Scripts portable between the two (BSD and GNU) therefore must be written with an explicit non-empty suffix attached to the `-i` option.  Note that such scripts may still be unportable to other POSIX systems; the `-i` option is not standardized (as you can tell from the divergent behaviour).